# "Add to cart" form alter

Tags: forms, commerce

want to change a few things with the hook they provide. The form id is *commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-626* and the submission button ID is *edit-submit*.

I created a module (*jch_test*) which contains the following code.

```php
function jch_test_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $line_item = $form_state['line_item'];
  $product = commerce_product_load($line_item->commerce_product[LANGUAGE_NONE]  [0]['product_id']);
  if ($product->type == 'product') {
    $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Test');
  }
}
```

The module loads, but the hook isn't invoked. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this:
function jch_test_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id){
drupal_set_message($form_id);
}
and now you will see the correct form ID as a drupal message so you can continue with the form. My best guessing is that your form ID in hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() is wrong.

Comment: code looks correct to me. Don't forget to clear your cache.

Comment: Also worth noting is $form_state['default_product'] holds the product currently selected on the Add to Cart form.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  //drupal_set_message($form_id);

  $form['submit']['#attributes']['value'] = t('Buy Now');

  /*
  $current_product = $form_state['default_product'];
  if ($current_product->type == 'product') {
    // Make alternations for products...
  }
  */

}
```

You can use the `$form_id` and/or `$current_product` to make custom alterations for a specific product(s) and/or product type(s).

Flush Drupal's caches so your custom form alteration hook will be recognized.

***Note***, I'd also like to point out that once a user changes a value on the add to cart form, and the form is reloaded via AJAX, `MY_MODULE_form_commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_alter()` will be called again, which is good.

However, it appears the `$form_state['default_product']->language` value may only be present the first time the page is loaded. Once the form is reloaded via AJAX, the `language` value may be empty in this hook, so watch out if your code is depending on it being there!

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$form['submit']['#attributes']['title'] = $form['submit']['#attributes']['value'] = t('Test');
```